# Anonymous function error : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm dynamically creating DOM elements in my Javascript code, and I am trying to add an anonymous function as an `onclick` event handler. Here is my code :

```
var onClickFunction = "(function(){var x = document.getElementById('onPrsClickButton'); x.value = this.id; x.click();})()";

var libelle = '<div onclick=' + onClickFunction + '></div>'
```

But whenever I click this `<div>`, the console gives me this error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Does anyone know why ? Thanks !

Comment: Your HTML ends up like `<div onclick=(function(){var x = document...`. Proper way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1v6qmfbr/

Comment: Also note that your string contains an IIFE, which is precisely not what you want for an `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed output will be

```html
<div onclick=(function(){var x = document.getElementById('onPrsClickButton'); x.value = this.id; x.click();})()></div>
```

This is not a valid HTML property value.
To make it valid you must surround the value in quotation marks (") or apostrophes (').
Some browsers can withstand some level of abuse, like not writing proper syntax, but that can't be trusted.

Also, your code have a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). This means that the code inside the function will be executed right away, not when you click (although I'm not sure the actual behavior in this particular case).

To make your sample work, you can do something like this:

```
var onClickFunction = function(){
    // Your event handler
};

var libelle = '<div onclick="javascript:onClickFunction();"></div>'
```

But the best approach (IMO) to solve your problem is to add a listener to your click, like this:

```
var libelle = document.getElementById("libelle");
libelle.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Your event handler
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks man. The only thing is I must address the onclick inside a String, because I am working on an older code that uses the `outerHTML` version of the DOM elements it creates. So I need the onclick function to be hard coded inside the string, this is why I am looking for a weird trick like this. Anyway, I found a solution for my problem : simply surround the onclick function with escaped quotation markes like this `var onClickFunction = "\"(function(){ })()\"";`

Comment: @metheM Remember to accept the answer if it solved your issue so others can be helped by it in the future.